# iOS: Cannot pass NSArray over a segue

Tags: ios, segue

I have 2 ViewControllers. I want to transfer an `NSArray` to the other via segue.

I have taken a look at all other questions on SO but still my code isn't working.
I want to transfer matchObject.

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "mapViewController.h"

//call map view
-(void) callMap {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"callMap" sender: self];
}

//pass data
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"callMap"]) {
        UINavigationController *nc = segue.destinationViewController;
        UIViewController *tvc = [nc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        tvc.matchObject = self.matchObject;
    }
}
```

I get an error on the last statement, saying property matchObject not found.

I have defined the property in 'mapViewController.h'

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *matchObject;
```

and synthesised it in 'mapViewController.m'

```
@synthesize matchObject = _matchObject;
```

I have connected the segue in the storyboard properly.

Comment: are you sure matchObject in mapViewController class contains data ?

Comment: No. I want to transfer data to mapViewController. matchObject is present in the ViewController.

Comment: tvc can't have a matchObject because it's a UINavigationController. Do you mean to pass it to the navigation controller's root view controller?

Comment: It's also going to tank because matchObject was synthesized as _matchObject.

Comment: @rdelmar I have updated the code to reference the UIViewController. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Is the error pointing to the left or right operand?

Comment: tvc isn't a UIViewController either, is it? Isn't it a mapViewController?

Comment: @D80Buckeye Left operand.

Comment: @rdelmar yes. mapViewController is the second viewController. I've embedded in a map in that view. I want to pass coordinates.

Comment: Then it should be mapViewController *tvc = [nc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: @rdelmar Cool, the error went away but when I run the program, the program crashes and I get this erro - -[mapViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Put in this log just before that line: NSLog (@"%@",[nc class]); and see what you get.

Comment: @rdelmar I get this - mapViewController

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33741/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-pritesh-desai)

Comment: There is therefore no navigation controller between the sourceVC and destinationVC. rdelma and myself assumed your destination is indeed a navigation controller. Ahmeds answer therefore works if destination is mapviewcontroller. Remember to name your classes with capital letters e.g MapViewController

Comment: @pnizzle yes, that and also I was accessing an ivar via a ' . ' instead of -> operator

Comment: If you really have matchObject as a property of mapViewController.h then using '.' should work fine e.g. tvc.matchObject = self.matchobject .  Once again if you have matchobject as a property of mapviewcontroller you do not need to override the setter method if all you do is assign the passed value to _matchObject (refering to ahmeds aster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with UINavigationController...

you can make a setter for matchObject in mapViewController class like this.

```
- (void)setMatchObject:(NSArray *)matchObject
{
   _matchObject = matchObject
}
```

and this updated prepareForSegue method...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"callMap"]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setMatchObject:) withObject:self.matchObject];

    }
}
```

Hope this works out for you.

Comment: I have updated the code to reference the UIViewController. Still getting the error.

Comment: thanks it worked but I had to use 'self->matchObject' in order to make it work.

Comment: From your question Pritesh, it seems the destination is a navigation controller. How did this answer work then? UINavigationController does not have a property matchObject. Your question is fine as is, all you need to do is change tvc from UIViewController to mapViewController (see my answer). There is also absolutely no need to override the setter. It can still be called if you indeed have matchObject as a property of mapviewController.

Comment: I just saw the discussion on your question. If you get the error saying [mapviewcontroller viewcontrollers] unrecognised selector it means you destination is actually not a navigation controller, and therefore this answer will work.

Answer (score 1):

UINavigationController has no property called matchObject. Neither does UIViewController. What you have to do is cast the destinationViewController to be an instance of your class.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"callMap"]) {
        MapViewController *tvc = (MapViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        tvc.matchObject = self.matchObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code to reference the UIViewController. Still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
UIViewController *tvc = [nc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
tvc.matchObject = self.matchObject;
```

You should instead have:

```
mapViewController *tvc = [nc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
tvc.matchObject = self.matchObject;
```

The reason why you are still getting an error is because UINavigationController does not have a property called matchObject.

And class names should start in capitals letters. You said your class is called mapViewController.m 
It should be MapViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work...
 Pass the array in the sender while performSegueWithIdentifier as shown below.

```
#import "mapViewController.h"

-(void) callMap {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"callMap" sender: matchObject];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"callMap"]) {
        UINavigationController *tvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        tvc.matchObject = sender;
    }
}
```